# How to add tag to soap XML Message

Tags: xml, xslt, soap, ibm-datapower

im using datapower SOA

i have an XML :

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body>
<data>data</data>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

i want to change it to :

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body>
<ns0:ReceptionRequest xmlns:ns0="ReceptionRequest">
<Message>
<data>data</data>
</Message>
</ns0:ReceptionRequest>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

please assist me with XSL

how do i add something before and after the tag

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns0="ReceptionRequest" exclude-result-prefixes="soap">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="soap:Body">
        <xsl:copy>
            <ns0:ReceptionRequest xmlns:ns0="ReceptionRequest">
                <Message>
                    <xsl:apply-templates />
                </Message>
            </ns0:ReceptionRequest>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The `<xsl:template match="soap:Body">` will make the new elements and copy the `<data>` element

Comment: If I have more tags under data , will it copy them too ?

Comment: @alex: Yes it will copy all elements that are within the ´<data>´ element

Comment: @alex has the answer been to satisfaction? If so please accepted the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code also which will copy  and its value.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>    

</xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match = "*[local-name() = 'Body']">

      <xsl:copy>
      <ns0:ReceptionRequest xmlns:ns0="ReceptionRequest">
        <Message>
           <xsl:copy-of  select ="*[local-name() = 'data']"/>

        </Message>
    </ns0:ReceptionRequest>
     </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```